# Repartition with a fixed minimum number of elements in each partition of the RDD using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD with the following number of elements in each partition (total number of partitions is `val numPart = 32`:

> 1351, 962, 537, 250, 80, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 88, 270, 635, 1028, 1388, 1509

To see the previous output I use this:

```
def countByPartition[A](anRdd: RDD[A]): RDD[Int] = anRdd.mapPartitions(iter => Iterator(iter.length))

println(countByPartition(anRdd).collect.mkString(", "))
```

I would like to have on each partition at least a minimum number of elements given by `val min = 5`.

I've tried to perform `anRdd.repartition(numPart)` and I get the following:

> 257, 256, 256, 256, 255, 255, 254, 253, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
>   252, 252, 251, 250, 249, 248, 248, 248, 248, 248, 261, 261, 260, 260,
>   259, 258, 258, 257

In this case, it was perfect because in each partition I have more than `min` elements. But it doesn't always gets the same and sometimes I get some partitions with values less than `min` value.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible and in general you need to choose partitioning so that the sizes are roughly even. [Partitioners](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.html) in Spark basically implement two methods `numPartitions` and `getPartition`. The latter is a function from a **single** key to a partition number so other elements and thus the potential size of partitions are not known at this point.